# ACL defaults for files vs directories: executable bit set unexpectedly

Tags: posix, acl

I set a default ACL on a directory, so that new files created inside it would be readable/writable by the user `daemon`. I used `rwX`, which should make new files inside it executable "only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user", according to the `setfacl` man page on my system.

But when I create a file inside that directory, it seems to be trying to give it executable permissions. Why is this?

(I see that they're blocked by the file's mask, but it's still causing problems later on.)

This is on CentOS 6.9, as root:

```
root$ mkdir foo
root$ setfacl -dR -m u:daemon:rwX foo
root$ touch foo/bar
root$ getfacl foo/bar
# file: foo/bar
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:daemon:rwx         #effective:rw-
group::r-x          #effective:r--
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is not an answer but a discussion, I should post this in the comments, but comment is not that convenient. Apologize first if you mind this.

> I used `rwX`, which should make **new files inside it** executable "only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user"

IMHO, this `X` will apply only to `foo` rather than the new files in `foo`. And since `foo` is a directory, `x` permission is guaranteed to be granted, so `setfacl -dR -m u:daemon:rwX foo` is equivalent to `setfacl -dR -m u:daemon:rwx foo`.

When a new file `bar` is created inside `foo`, it automatically inherits its parent's default ACL as its Access ACL. And the ACL entries that correspond to the traditional UNIX permission sets are masked (ANDed) against the `mode` argument of `open(2)/mkdir(2)`. `default:user:daemon:rwx` does not correspond to the traditional permission, so it remains unchanged. `ACL_MASK` corresponds to `file group` so that it is masked and thus `x` permission is removed.

```bash
$ mkdir foo

$ setfacl -dR -m u:daemon:rwX foo

$ getfacl -c foo
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:daemon:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

$ touch foo/bar

$ getfacl -c foo/bar
user::rw-
user:daemon:rwx                 #effective:rw-
group::r-x                      #effective:r--
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Because `x` permission is removed from `ACL_MASK`, then `x` on `user:daemon` becomes useless, and this is what `#effective:rw-` in `user:daemon:rwx #effective:rw-` means.

> (I see that they're blocked by the file's mask, but it's still causing problems later on.)

Seems that everything is normal, what problems were you facing later on?